# Reactive Extensions put action in onComplete or using Concat?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

If P.DoWork() depends on the completion of both d1.DoWork() and d2.DoWork():

```
  p
 / \
d1  d2
```

are putting p.DoWork() in onComplete:

```
    p.Dependencies.ToObservable()
                  .SelectMany(
                    x=>Observable.Return(x)
                                 .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                                 .Select(a => a.Dowork())
                    )
                 .Subscript(_={},()=p.DoWork())
```

or using Concat:

```
  var po =Observable.Return(p)
            .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                    .Select(a => a.Dowork());
  var ds = p.Dependencies.ToObservable()
              .SelectMany(
                x=>Observable.Return(x)
                             .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                             .Select(a => a.Dowork())
                );
  ds.Concat(po).subscribe();
```

the same?